# How to return a MySql record when value BETWEEN 2 column values?

Tags: mysql

We have 3 particular columns orderTotalFrom and orderTotalTo and ShippingPrice.
We are trying to determine if a price falls between the 2 column values.
For example, assume we have an order that is 250.0000, we would want to return the row with a shipping price of 0.0000

```
orderTotalFrom orderTotalTo   ShippingPrice
0.0000         19.9900        6.9500
20.0000        39.9900        7.9500
40.0000        59.9900        8.9500
60.0000        74.9900        9.9500
75.0000        999999.0000    0.0000
```

Could please show me how this is done in MySql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select ShippingPrice 
from MyTable
where 250.0000 between orderTotalFrom and orderTotalTo
```

Comment: Thanks RedFilter.. now I need to convert it to Hibernates HQL and I am REALLY hoping it supports BETWEEN! :)

Comment: @JoJo `BETWEEN` is supported by HQL, so the query should work as-is.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ShippingPrice FROM myTable WHERE 250 BETWEEN orderTotalFrom AND orderTotalTo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  250000 between orderTotalFrom and orderTotalTo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select ShippingPrice
from your_table
where orderTotalFrom <= 250.0000
and orderTotalTo >= 250.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ShippingPrice FROM table WHERE orderTotalFrom<=xxx AND orderTotalTo>=xxx;
```